# How can i know my privilege on stack overflow?

Tags: support

How to check my privilege and what activities i can perform on stack overflow with my current reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

It will show you all the privileges and the ones you have are marked with a checkmark.
And you can check other people's privileges from this link.

`https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/user-id-goes-here`.
For example here are my privileges:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/146.
or yours 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/19026

Comment: Thanks Marius , its really helpful